# how to cast to a clickable link and concatinate url together in sql

Tags: sql, join, casting, hyperlink, concatenation

I want to concatenate to a link and then instead of showing the link as 'http.....' I want to show it as a 'link' that is clickable

| doc_link |
| --- |
| link |

I get the error

Type l is not a defined system type.

```
select CAST(concat('https://somthing.co.il/','/parameter/') as link) as doc_link
from table
```

how to write is correct?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what's your database?

Comment: Does your dbms have a link _data type_?